# what does -v and -k mean in the curl?

Tags: http, curl

I read this whole page

http://conqueringthecommandline.com/book/curl#cha-3_footnote-1

and I didn't see any `-v` or `-k` options for cURL

I have this curl request:

```
curl -v -k --user "bla/test@bla.com:BlaBla" \
    "theUrlToTheServer" | xmllint --format - > something.xml
```

I started by trying to understand what do `-v` and `-k` mean, but I couldn't understand them, may you help please

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**-k, --insecure**

(SSL) This option explicitly allows curl to perform "insecure" SSL connections and transfers. All SSL connections are attempted to be made secure by using the CA certificate bundle installed by default. This makes all connections considered "insecure" fail unless -k, --insecure is used.

See this online resource for further details: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

**-v  - verbose**

That means print everything while executing.

Comment: please could you tell me what about the others `--users` (is the same as `-u` ) ? and `| xmllint --format - > something.xml`

Comment: For more info on curl https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html and the output from curl will be piped to xmllint for formating as xml.